# How to convert array of array of strings into an object where each string is the key of an object that includes the next

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array formatted like so

```
const array = [
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_pro'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_air'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'phones', 'iphone'],
  ['technology', 'samsung', 'phones', 'Galaxy S21'],
]
```

And I need to convert it to an object formatted like so:

```
{
  technology: {
    apple: {
      computers: {
        macbook_pro: {},
        macbook_air: {}
      },
      phones: {
        iphone: {}
      }
    },
    samsung: {
      phones: {
        galaxy_s21: {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried getting it done with a two forEach loops but I keep getting stuck.

Comment: Do you know that the size of the array is 4 always (`[4][]`) ? Or this is a question for a generic transformation of a matrix to a graph ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating an object accumulator.

In every iteration, set a `current` to the accumulator and iterate over the current list using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). If `current` doesn't have a property, set the value to `{}` using the [`nullish operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). Then, reset `current` to it to be used in the next iteration.

```js
const array = [
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_pro'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_air'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'phones', 'iphone'],
  ['technology', 'samsung', 'phones', 'Galaxy S21'],
];

const res = array.reduce((acc, props) => {
  let current = acc;
  props.forEach(prop => {
    current[prop] ??= {};
    current = current[prop];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: With `??=` being the [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: Legend, thank you so much for the code and even more so for the clear explanation. Also interesting to read about the logical nullish assignment. I didn't see that before. Have a good one!

Answer (score 1):

`Array.reduce` implementation is added below

- Loop through the input `array`
- Loop through each node in the input array.
- Check if accumulator has the node with that key.
- If no create an empty object as that node in accumulator.
- Keep the newly created node or existing node as temp value.
- This temp variable keeps on drilling your accumulator object inside the loop.

```js
const array = [
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_pro'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'computers', 'macbook_air'],
  ['technology', 'apple', 'phones', 'iphone'],
  ['technology', 'samsung', 'phones', 'Galaxy S21'],
]
const output = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let temp = acc;
  curr.forEach((node) => {
    if (!temp[node]) {
      temp[node] = {}
    }
    temp = temp[node]
  })
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output)
```